# Extjs4 how can I disable, the rowediting plugin in a grid?

Tags: plugins, grid, extjs4, editing

I want to disable the rowediting plugin depends on a combo selection, I have the grid reference. How can I disable it? (I try to destroy it, but then when I close the window, i get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getView' of undefined ".

Answer (score 2):

Return `false` from the RowEditing `beforeedit` event.

```
listeners: {
    beforeedit: function(editor, context){
        if(comboBox.getValue() === /* whatever conditions you have */){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also set `context.cancel = true` to achieve the same effect, but I don't really see the point in it since returning `false` from a `beforexyz` event is a standard idiom in the Ext JS 4 library.